# CSS link padding added via Javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I tried searching for an answer first, but this seems to be an edge case.

I'm adding a class to a link via JavaScript (well jQuery actually but I don't think it matters in this case). The class adds an icon as a background image and some padding. The padding and background image fail to appear on certain links. The problem shows up in IE8, but surprisingly works fine in IE7. I can't test IE9/10. Works fine in Firefox.

I reduced the code down to a bare minimum and created a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/fsdcu/

I'll try adding the code here.

```
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: #fff }
a:hover { background-color: transparent; color: #c30 }
ul { padding-left: 40px }
.iconNewWindowLeave { padding-right: 15px; background-color: #ccc }
</style>
<ul>
    <li style="float: left"><a class="iconNewWindowLeave" href="#">left link</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: right">some stuff on the right</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li style="float: left"><a class="linkExternal" href="#">left link</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: right">some stuff on the right</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.linkExternal').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('iconNewWindowLeave');
});
</script>
```

I've removed the image from the example and added a background color for illustration. In IE 8, the second link doesn't have right padding. Hovering over the link, adds the padding. If I remove the a:hover CSS, hovering doesn't correct the problem. If I remove the float, the problem goes away. If I remove any of the other CSS, the problem goes away.

So I've narrowed down the cause(s), but I don't know what to do about it. I don't want to remove or change the existing code. It's all required for the site layout. If possible, I'd like to *add* some CSS or JavaScript to fix it. It's a minor issue, but it's bugging me. I'm also curious as to whether or not the problem appears in newer versions of IE.

Comment: i tried [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/fsdcu/)  and checked in IE7, 8 and 9 also and working fine as i can see padding-right on both link.

Comment: @maxterner did you try the code above as is or try my jsFiddle? I just noticed that it works when the JavaScript is in the body below the element as in the code above. But when it runs onDomReady as in the jsFiddle, then it fails.

Comment: yes @toxalot this link i tried http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/fsdcu/

Comment: Must be really edge case. Strange that it works in IE8 for some and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add : a `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;` to .iconNewWindowLeave

```
.iconNewWindowLeave { padding-right: 15px; background-color: #ccc; display:inline-block; }
```

(not tested)

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I'm not sure yet if it will have any other implications.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have some floating containers on the page, always clear the parent container.
In your case add a style clear:left on the ul. That should work.

And in case you are using many float throughout your application, better add a clearfix class on the parent container.

Comment: My full code does have CSS to clear the float. I removed it here for simplicity and just in case it was part the problem.